# WorkManager start Worker twice

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I have a set of big tasks which I want to execute in background:

1. Loding data
2. Parsing bunch of files and storing them in `Room`

For this reason I created unique chain of `Worker`'s with the same `tag`.

```
class GtfsStaticManager() {
    private val workerManager = WorkManager.getInstance()

    override fun load() {
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()

        val inputData = GtfsStaticLoadDataWorker.inputData(staticUrl, cacheDir)
        // 1. Loading data
        val downloadWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(GtfsStaticLoadDataWorker::class.java)
            .addTag("GTFS")
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .setInputData(inputData)
            .build()

        // 2. List of Workers to parse and store data to the Room
        val parseWorkers = GtfsFile.values().map {
            OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(GtfsStaticParseFileWorker::class.java)
                .setInputData(GtfsStaticParseFileWorker.inputData(it.file, cacheDir + File.separator + "feed"))
                .addTag("GTFS")
                .build()
        }

        workerManager
            .beginUniqueWork("GTFS", ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, downloadWorkRequest)
            .then(parseWorkers)
            .enqueue()
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except one thing: one of the files has 4 million records and it takes around 10-15 minutes to finish it. After some time I noticed that it was enqueued again **BUT** the first job was still running, so as result I have 2 huge jobs running in background and of course my data was duplicated.

I followed [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager-kt/#0) tutorial, did I miss something?

Below is my `Worker` with parsing logic:

```
class GtfsStaticParseFileWorker(
    context: Context,
    workerParameters: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, workerParameters) {
    private val fileName: String get() = inputData.getString(FILE_NAME) ?: ""
    private val cacheDir: String get() = inputData.getString(UNZIP_FOLDER) ?: ""

    companion object {
        private const val FILE_NAME = "FILE_NAME"
        private const val UNZIP_FOLDER = "UNZIP_FOLDER"
        fun inputData(fileName: String, cacheDir: String) = Data
            .Builder()
            .putString(FILE_NAME, fileName)
            .putString(UNZIP_FOLDER, cacheDir)
            .build()
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val db = LvivTransportTrackerDataBase.getUpdateInstance(applicationContext)
        val agencyRepository = AgencyRepository(db.agencyDao())
        val calendarRepository = CalendarRepository(db.calendarDao())
        val calendarDateRepository = CalendarDateRepository(db.calendarDateDao())
        val routeRepository = RouteRepository(db.routeDao())
        val stopTimeRepository = StopTimeRepository(db.stopTimeDao())
        val stopRepository = StopRepository(db.stopDao())
        val tripRepository = TripRepository(db.tripDao())

        val file = File(cacheDir + File.separator + fileName)
        val fileType = GtfsFile.from(fileName) ?: return Result.failure()

        when (fileType) {
            GtfsFile.Agency -> agencyRepository.deleteAll()
            GtfsFile.CalendarDates -> calendarDateRepository.deleteAll()
            GtfsFile.Calendar -> calendarRepository.deleteAll()
            GtfsFile.Routes -> routeRepository.deleteAll()
            GtfsFile.StopTimes -> stopTimeRepository.deleteAll()
            GtfsFile.Stops -> stopRepository.deleteAll()
            GtfsFile.Trips -> tripRepository.deleteAll()
        }

        FileInputStream(file).use { fileInputStream ->
            InputStreamReader(fileInputStream).use inputStreamReader@{ inputStreamReader ->
                val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
                val headers = bufferedReader.readLine()?.split(',') ?: return@inputStreamReader
                var line: String? = bufferedReader.readLine()

                while (line != null) {
                    val mapLine = headers.zip(line.split(',')).toMap()

                    Log.d("GtfsStaticParse", "$fileType: $line")
                    when (fileType) {
                        GtfsFile.Agency -> agencyRepository.create(AgencyEntity(mapLine))
                        GtfsFile.CalendarDates -> calendarDateRepository.create(CalendarDateEntity(mapLine))
                        GtfsFile.Calendar -> calendarRepository.create(CalendarEntity(mapLine))
                        GtfsFile.Routes -> routeRepository.create(RouteEntity(mapLine))
                        GtfsFile.StopTimes -> stopTimeRepository.create(StopTimeEntity(mapLine))
                        GtfsFile.Stops -> stopRepository.create(StopEntity(mapLine))
                        GtfsFile.Trips -> tripRepository.create(TripEntity(mapLine))
                    }

                    line = bufferedReader.readLine()
                }
            }
        }

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

P.S. my dependency is `implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worker classes, in WorkManager, have an execution limit of 10 minutes.
From [WorkManager guide on how to handle cancellation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work.html?hl=es#stopping):

> The system instructed your app to stop your work for some reason. This can happen if you exceed the execution deadline of 10 minutes. The work is scheduled for retry at a later time.

In your case, you're not handling the stopping of the work but WorkManager will ignore any result because it marked the job an "cancelled" and it will execute it again when possible.

This can result in the double execution that you're experiencing.

It's difficult to suggest an alternative approach without knowing more about the goal you want achieve however, as a general rule, WorkManager is intended for deferrable tasks that need a guaranteed execution.

[WorkManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) has been expanded after the 1.0 release and you can find more information there.

Comment: Thanks, this limitation is new for me. So in my case, to handle correct `cancel` status I should change my `while` loop to something like this: `while (line != null || !isStopped)`? My goal is very simple, after I downloaded a `zip` file I need to `unzip` it and parse `csv` files in it. The problem in my case that one file has 4 **million** rows, and storing them in `room` take a while.

Comment: evaluating `isStopped` is one part.
Keep in mind that WorkManager, in this situation, will ignore the return value from your Worker and reschedule it.
This means that you need to keep track of where you arrived processing the data, before exiting from your Worker or, next time it is executed, you can end up processing the same data twice and be catch by the same 10 minute limit.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the best option for storing my `progress` value (static variable, shared preferences, etc)? `Android` world is new for me, so I'm not sure how to do it best.

Comment: Shared Prefs seems a good option in this case: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

but I don't know the whole application/use case so... read the docs and check if this solution works for your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check the downloaded file is present on the path where file is downloaded and then store the bytes in SharedPreferences inside loop which are read previously from the downloaded path and once your Job started again , then first check the downloaded bytes and Next time start from that offset.

Example Code:

```
RandomAccessFile seeker = new RandomAccessFile(fname, "r");
seeker.seek(readOffset()); // move to the offset
seeker.readLine(); // and read the String
```

If you need to check the same for Database entries , then mark status as "Success" for the rows which are done to skip that for the next time.